# Android app development: remove layout bar

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hello"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

When I run it it creates a Hello World application with a bar on top that says Hello. The Hello string is stored in @string/app_name and presumably linked by the starred line. I want to remove the label so I deleted the starred line, but the label still showed. How does Android know where to get the Hello string since I have removed the line that tells Android to look in app_name? How can I remove the label?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by putting the following code in your onCreate:
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Put it before this line:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't fully answer my question. How does Android know where to get the Hello string since I have removed the line that tells Android to look in app_name?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the question. The App Name is taken from the Android Manifest file. I'm not exactly sure what is it called like but you should be able to find it easilly.